# Adding <br> to String using fn.join

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have the following JSTL code in my JSP.  I am splitting a String into an array using the newline character (\n) as the delimiter.  I am then trying to add a `<br />` to each member and then display it on the page, but none of the elements are being displayed.  I'm just getting white space.  Can anyone help me?

```
<c:set var="comment" value="${bulletin.note}" />
<c:set var="comment" value="${fn:split(comment, '\\\\n')}" />
<c:forEach var="line" items="${comment}">
    <c:set var="line" value="${fn.join(line, '<br />')}" />
    <c:out value="${line}" /><br>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by writing the following custom tag:

```
public class NotePrint extends SimpleTagSupport {
    private String note;

    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {
        PageContext pageContext = (PageContext) getJspContext();
        JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut();
        note.replace("\n\n", "\n ");
        String[] noteArray = note.split("\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < noteArray.length; i++) {
            if (i == noteArray.length - 1) {
                out.println(noteArray[i]);

            } else {
                out.println(noteArray[i] + "<br />");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sample codes, like your type:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>JSTL fn:split() example</title>
</head>
<body>
<c:set var="msg" value="This is an example of JSTL function"/>
<c:set var="arrayofmsg" value="${fn:split(msg,' ')}"/>
<c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="6">
 arrayofmsg[${i}]: ${arrayofmsg[i]}<br>
</c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `comment` contains an array of data. You just have to iterate on this array using `c:foreach`:

```
<c:set var="comment" value="${bulletin.note}" />
<c:set var="comment" value="${fn:split(comment, '\\\\n')}" />
<c:forEach var="line" items="${comment}">
    <c:out value="${line}" /><br>
</c:forEach>
```

And if you want to use [JSTL join](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/join.fn.html), the syntax is `fn:join` (and not `fn.join`).